# Best Practice for clothing items (zip) to attach to clothing (jacket) with cloth simulation

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

The objective is to create a realistic jacket which has zipped pockets on each side, but for it to work with cloth physics enabled.

The problem is to find the best solution for having a separate object, such as a zip, work with the simulation.

What would be the best practice for this, or is it simply best to cheat it?

What I've tried so far:

1. Create the zip as a separate mesh
2. Create an empty and vertex parent it to the pocket.
3. Parent the zip to the empty, so the zip
   follows the jacket during simulation.
4. Use weight paint and 'pinning' to reduce amount of 
   bending/deformation around the pockets.
5. Use shrinkwrap to 'attach' the zips to the
   pocket and to deform with jacket during simulation.

The problem, is that the shrinkwrap still deforms / stretches the mesh with unwanted results -

[image]

Blend file (updated):

[image]

Comment: i don't know, never tried, but imho the zip should deform at least along the line, to be realistic... thay are not undeformable objects, they usually follow the tissue the're bound to, although a bit more stiffly...

Comment: Granted, it should deform slightly. But to be more specific, it's the zipper's teeth that shouldn't which is the result I'm getting.

Comment: probably having at least a partial file to see your setup, and try in some way... if you can, upload to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ (permanent storage)

Comment: I've now uploaded the test file, thanks @m.ardito

Comment: The blend file you uploaded doesn't quite match what is shown in your image. Let me know exactly what you need to achieve and I'll see if I can create my own setup. You need to specify:1. is it going to be used in animations? 2.Will the jacket eventually goes onto some character's body? If not, where do you need it? 3. Do you need to animate the zipping-unzipping?

Comment: Thanks @SVAFnemesis. Please try to download the blend file again. In answer to your questions: 1) Yes 2) Yes, on a realistic human mesh, however I had to remove the model so that it didn't exceed the file size limit, instead I've replaced it with a low-poly mesh. If you would prefer with the original mesh, I can upload the file to my server. 3)No, just as is, animating with the cloth simulation.